# highcharts 3 addPoint Point order

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts 2, it was easy to add a point using `series.addPoint(p)` where the x value of that point fell between the x-values of two existing points.

Example:  Let's say you wanted to create a chart with one series containing two points:

```
var p1 = {x: 100, y: 50};
var p2 = {x: 200, y: 40};

var data = [];
data.push(p1);
data.push(p1);

var c = new Highcharts.Chart({
  ...//code omitted
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  ...//code omitted

});
```

In version two you could call add a point between those two by going:

```
var p3 = {x: 150, y: 60};

c.series[0].addPoint(p3, true);
```

For 'line' charts, highcharts 2 would automatically determine that the x value of p3 falls between the x values of p1 and p2 and so the line would be plotted through the points in the order: p1, p3, p2.

We are finding that in highcharts 3, the line gets plotted through the points in the order p1, p2, p3 - which implies that it "turns back on itself".

I have prepared the following jsFiddle examples, which add 50 points to an existing series with randomized x and y value.:

Highcharts 2.1.9:  http://jsfiddle.net/HdNh2/4/

Highcharts 3.0.0: http://jsfiddle.net/HdNh2/5/

Is this something that could be fixed or do we need to try and circumvent the issue?

Thanks in advance...

H

Comment: Since Highcharts 2.2.x data for xAxis have to be sorted ascending.

Comment: Thanks Pawel.  It's a bit of a pitty because the pre 2.2.x functionality was particularly useful for one of our scenarios, but we should be able to sort it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to close this issue:  Highcharts has confirmed that the logic changed since 2.2.x.

In our case it was simple enough to just re-render the entire chart, but I suspect `series.setData()` would also have been an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround. This will sort points on their x-values as they're added manually. This *events* object is in the *chart* object options block.

```
events: {
    click: function(e) {
        // find the clicked values and the series
        var series = this.series[DIA.currentSeriesIndex],
            x = parseFloat(e.xAxis[0].value),
            y = parseFloat(e.yAxis[0].value);

        // Add it
        series.addPoint([x, y]);

        if ( series.data.length > 1) {
            // grab last point object in array
            var point = series.data[series.data.length-1];
            // sort the point objects on their x values
            series.data.sort(function (a, b)
            {
                //Compare "a" and "b" and return -1, 0, or 1
                return (a.x - b.x);
            });
            // force a redraw
            point.update();
        }
    }
}
```